# Make a textblock opaque for mouseclicks - so parenting panel's event doesn't fire

Tags: c#, wpf, events

Well how would one make it so that a textblock (or whatever) frameworkelement has a click event. But if that click event is fired the parent's (grid) click event won't fire. - The parent's click event should fire if not clicked on the textbox/whatever.

This is shown in a simple example:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace testit
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            Grid mainGrid = (Grid)FindName("MainGrid");
            mainGrid.MouseLeftButtonDown += ClickInNowhere;
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock {
                Text = "hello\nworld"
            };
            tb.MaxWidth = 100;
            tb.MaxHeight = 100;
            mainGrid.Children.Add(tb);
            tb.MouseLeftButtonDown += ClickOnBox;
        }

        private void ClickInNowhere(object o, MouseButtonEventArgs args) {
            tb.Text = "hello\nworld";
        }

        private void ClickOnBox(object o, MouseButtonEventArgs args) {
            tb.Text += "a";
            //do something so that the "MouseLeftButtonDown" of the main window doesn't fire
        }
    }
}
```

With the xml format:

```
<Window x:Class="testit.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testit"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Background="#FFC8C8C8" />
</Window>
```

Notice that hte grid has a background to make it react to mouse events. There should be two cases:

- Click on the textbox: the text in the box is appended by "a"
- Click outside the box: the text in the textbox gets reset to "hello\nworld"

This obviously doesn't happen: when ran through a debugger it can be seen that both events are fired.

So how to make the textblock opaque for mouse events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to say, that event is handled:

```
private void ClickInNowhere(object o, MouseButtonEventArgs args) {
        tb.Text = "hello\nworld";
        args.Handled = true;
}
```

MouseButtonEventArgs derrive from RoutedEventArgs, which has the Handled property, here you can read more about it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.handled(v=vs.110).aspx

Also I recommend to read about event bubbling: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/464926/To-bubble-or-tunnel-basic-WPF-events

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to mark the mouse event as handled.

```
private void ClickOnBox(object o, MouseButtonEventArgs args) {
        tb.Text += "a";
        //do something so that the "MouseLeftButtonDown" of the main window doesn't fire
        args.Handled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set **Handle** property to true in **MouseButtonEventArgs**.
Because it is a bubble event and by setting Handle to true it will not be handled in parent.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace testit
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Grid mainGrid = (Grid)FindName("MainGrid");
            mainGrid.MouseLeftButtonDown += ClickInNowhere;
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock
            {
                Text = "hello\nworld"
            };
            tb.MaxWidth = 100;
            tb.MaxHeight = 100;
            mainGrid.Children.Add(tb);
            tb.MouseLeftButtonDown += ClickOnBox;
        }

        private void ClickInNowhere(object o, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
        {
            tb.Text = "hello\nworld";
        }

        private void ClickOnBox(object o, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
        {
            tb.Text += "a";
            args.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```